# Cannot get FoxPro SQL statement to execute properly from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm hoping someone here can help with a problem I'm having with `C#` and `FoxPro database`.

Below you will find the complete method for reading from a FoxPro (SQL server) database.
The problem I'm having is in the statement `SqlDataReader FP_Reader = FoxProSQLCmd.ExecuteReader();`
When I step through the code and hit this line, it always jumps to the catch routine.  I'm assuming it is something in the SQL statement that is not formatted or is invalid.  Visual Studio does not give me any errors other than this message

> "A first chance exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll".

This message is displayed in the Debug output window.

Also, in the SQL statement string `FoxProSQLCommand = "SELECT dfree FROM dbo.gph_description_master WHERE dfree = 'CALIFORNIA BRANDS'";`
  I cannot use the `SELECT *` statement because I do not have access rights to all the fields in the database.

The SQL statement below runs and excutes properly from SQL Server management studio

```
SELECT TOP 100000 [dfree]
      FROM [INTRANET].[dbo].[gph_description_master]
      WHERE dfree = 'California brands'
```

and the code is:

```
private string GetFilenameFromFoxPro(string TemplateNum)
    {
        string TemplateFileNameInFoxPro = TemplateNum.Substring(8); 
        // string FoxProCommand = "SELECT dfree FROM dbo.gph_description_master WHERE tempno='" +                   TemplateFileNameInFoxPro + "'";  // use this command once access has been granted to column 'tempno' in database table.

        string FoxProSQLCommand = "SELECT dfree FROM dbo.gph_description_master WHERE dfree =     'CALIFORNIA BRANDS'";  // This is basically test code at the moment.

        //  string FoxProCommand = "SELECT [dfree] FROM [INTRANET].[dbo.gph_description_master]  WHERE dfree = 'CALIFORNIA BRANDS'";

        string DatabaseCommentField = "";
        SqlConnection FoxProDB = new SqlConnection();


        try 
           {
           FoxProDB.ConnectionString = ("User id=FoxProTemps;" +  
                                        "password=TemplatesRule!;" +          
                                        "Data Source=SQLPROD01;" +        // This is the server
                                        "Initial Catalog=INTRANET;"       // This is the database     
                                        ); 
           FoxProDB.Open();
           MessageBox.Show("FoxPro OPENED!");
           }

        catch
          {
            MessageBox.Show("FoxPro did not open!");
            return("Cannot Connect to TemplatesDatabase");
          }

        try
          {
            SqlCommand FoxProSQLCmd = new SqlCommand(FoxProCommand);              
            SqlDataReader FP_Reader = FoxProSQLCmd.ExecuteReader();  // This is the line that is giving me grief.

            while (FP_Reader.Read())
              {
                DatabaseCommentField = FP_Reader.ToString();
              }
          }
        catch
          {
            MessageBox.Show("SQL Command or SQL Reader did not work!");
            return (TemplateFileNameInFoxPro);
          }
            // ToDo:
            // Add code to parse Database comment fields so Template filename can be extracted
            // TemplateFileNameInFoxPro = DatabaseCommentField          
        FoxProDB.Close();
        return TemplateFileNameInFoxPro;

    }
```

Please share your thoughts, suggestions or criticisms.
I've tried to include as much information as possible.

Thanks,
MTH

Comment: Use `OleDbCommand` (and `OleDbConnection`), not `SqlCommand` - `SqlCommand` is for SQL Server only.

Comment: Reading more closely, I'm confused - FoxPro is NOT a SQL Server database, but you're using `dbo.`  Which is it?

Comment: Your tag says sql-server-2008, but your question references FoxPro.  Which DBMS are you using?  FoxPro != SQL Server.  Also, FoxPro has been discontinued over 7 years ago...why are you using that anyway, is this legacy software?

Comment: Good questions and thanks for the responses.  I called our IT department and here is what I was told:  The graphics department enters the information into an old FoxPro front end database.  The information is then moved into MS SQL server 2008.  SQL Server is where I'm trying to access the information from.  Also, yes FoxPro is old, but that's what our graphics department is using.

Comment: After 2 weeks of waiting, I finally got access to the 2nd field in the database. My new SQL statement reads as follow: string FoxProCommand1 = "SELECT tempno, dfree FROM dbo.gph_description_master WHERE tempno = '" + TemplateFileNameInFoxPro + "'";  I am still unable to access the field in the database via C#, but I can run the SQL statement SELECT [tempno]
      ,[dfree]
  FROM [INTRANET].[dbo].[gph_description_master]
  WHERE tempno = '92990'  in SQL Server Management studio just fine and see the data I want.

Comment: Finally got this working!!

I changed my SQL statement to:  "SELECT dfree FROM dbo.gph_description_master WHERE tempno = '" + TemplateFileNameInFoxPro + "'"

Then added the connection string to the SQL command: SqlCommand FoxProSQLCmd = new SqlCommand(FoxProCommand5, FoxProDB);

Then changed the while statement to read:
while (FP_Reader.Read())
      {
        DatabaseCommentField = FP_Reader["dfree"].ToString();
      }

Now my program is doing EXACTLY what I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working!! I changed my SQL statement to: "SELECT dfree FROM dbo.gph_description_master WHERE tempno = '" + TemplateFileNameInFoxPro + "'" Then added the connection string to the SQL command: SqlCommand FoxProSQLCmd = new SqlCommand(FoxProCommand5, FoxProDB); Then changed the while statement to read: while (FP_Reader.Read()) { DatabaseCommentField = FP_Reader["dfree"].ToString(); } Now my program is doing EXACTLY what I want! –